# How to restore Virtualbox ? lost last two months of work

Tags: resize, virtual-machine, virtualbox, snapshot

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=90893

Hello im desesperate and need help because i have lost about two months of work in my Windows 10 guest system. 
Everything worked smoothly till i need to have more free space ( although i have a dynamic hd). So i have follow some tutorials and made some changes:

1 - I have the original almost full disk in: /Maquinas VirtualBox/Clientes Windows/Windows 10/Windows10-disk1.vmdk

2 - I made a copy in an external usb device.

3 - Convert to vdi: VBoxManage clonehd /media/eduardo/Seagate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive/Windows10-disk1.vmdk /media/eduardo/Seagate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive/Windows10-disk.vdi --format vdi

4 - Tried to resize the disk ( from 80gb to 100gb): VBoxManage modifyhd /media/eduardo/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Windows10-disk1.vmdk --resize 100000 and VBoxManage modifymedium disk /media/eduardo/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Windows10-disk1.vmdk --resize 100000 ( think this could be an error as i had to chage size to vdi file).

5 - Then i had to change the uuid ( because an error of uuid in use arised):VBoxManage internalcommands sethduuid "/media/eduardo/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Windows10-disk1.vmdk"

6 - Then comeback to: VBoxManage clonehd "/media/eduardo/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Windows10-disk1.vmdk" " " --format vdi

and resize VBoxManage modifymedium disk "/media/eduardo/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Windows10-disk.vdi" --resize 120000

I tried to change my virutal machine with the new vdi file to test if everything was fine ( change my /Maquinas VirtualBox/Clientes Windows/Windows 10/Windows10-disk1.vmdk disk connection to the new/media/eduardo/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Windows10-disk.vdi) . But i detected somewhat that the system has turned back two months ago !!!!

I was not worried and decided to go back to my "untouch" vmdk, but the most strange thing is that the original "untouch" file: /Maquinas VirtualBox/Clientes Windows/Windows 10/Windows10-disk1.vmdk also boots with things and files and state about two months ago. So im quite nervous.

Selección_058.png
Selección_058.png (65.19 KiB) Viewed 9 times

As watching files the 6c***** has to be the "good status" as was modified yesterday at night. Here is my file manager:

Selección_059.png
Selección_059.png (54.06 KiB) Viewed 9 times

Here is my VM ( made an snapshot about two months ago i dont remember when exactly)

```
https://imagebin.ca/v/4QlKV3Equ1fW
```

My log:

https://pastebin.com/JSLFRNMs

```
Hope anybody can help...
```

i think that the key is to return somewhat to 6c**** state of my vmdk file, i dont understand how this vmdk got changed as it was not touched

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. It was nothing to do with resizing disks. I select the { 6cc3c***-*****} hard disk ( although it was "only" 47 gb), for surprise for me it load its "snapshot" part of 47 gb with the whole disk windows10-disk1.vmdk....

Sorry for my bad english, but its difficult to explain, in the settings of the virtual machine in storage section, select as main disk the 6cc***** and start/boot the VM

Once was loaded and working fine, i deleted the snapshot ( to bring all together to the present state) and then made another snapshot for backup.

Thanks